# iOS Custom navigation back bar button action not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation

I try to change the navigation back bar button.

My Code will push self view controller.

So I need when the push the second view controller, the navigation back bar button (left bar button) is show home images bar button item .

Then after push self third view controller will show default backbarbutton and custom action.

But when I push over the third view, the custom action always not work.

Have anyone known why or how to fixed the problem?

stack:

Main -> push(main filelist) -> push(child view controller)(show default back nav bar button have arrow, but will custom action) -> push...(same child action)...-> push...

my part code below:

```
       NSInteger nmvcCount = 0;
        NSArray* navControllersAry = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

        for(NSInteger j = 0 ; j <= [navControllersAry count]-1; j++){


            if( [[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:j] isKindOfClass:[FMVC class]]){
             nmvcCount = nmvcCount + 1;
            }

        }

        if(nmvcCount == 1 ){
            // home bar button is using storyboard draw
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = self.homeBarBtn;

        }else{
           self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = nil;
            [self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTarget:self];
            [self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(popAndOtherProcess:)];

        }

 }

 ....

 -(void) popAndOtherProcess:(id)btn{
  NSLog(@"it work");
 }
```

thank you very much.

Comment: Kinldy be more clear. We could not get what you want to achive. What is custom action you are assigning to back button. ??

Comment: I need custom action , but it is not enter the popAndOtherProcess method. In short, In same view controller, some situation I need the back bar button is use the  left bar button item replace. some situation the left bar button item is dismiss , using the default back bar button (have arrow) but custom the back bar button action.

Comment: Now code , the popAndOtherProcess always not enter .

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code:**

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                           initWithTitle:@"Flip"                                            
                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                           target:self 
                           action:@selector(backView:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

**Use method like:**

```
-(IBAction)backView
```